# dot product of vectors, matrix inversion, eigenvalues calculation in boost

Tags: c++, boost, matrix

Does *boost or open CV* contains dot product of vectors, matrix inversion, eigenvalues calculation of matrices?

Answer (score 3):

Boost has that: 
http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/cgi-bin/boost_wiki/wiki.pl?LU_Matrix_Inversion
and for more information about ublas:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/overview.htm

Answer (score 3):

Also you can find information about OpenCV operations using following links.
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/operations_on_arrays.html
http://note.sonots.com/OpenCV/MatrixOperations.html